# iOS Swift PDFViewer native toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf

I want to create a download button for my `PDFView`, but I was only able to do it by adding a **Toolbar** with a **Button** to the same `ViewController` that contained the `PDFView` and I added the download function to that button.

I used `UIActivityViewController`. The **Button** on the **Toolbar** used this to show the View where the user can download the ***PDF***.

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: 
[self.pdfDownloadableData], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Is there any way where I can do the same without adding a **Toolbar** and a **Button** manually to the `ViewController`? Does the `PDFViewer` has some native way to add this **Button** to itself somehow?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller)

A view controller that previews, opens, or prints(download) files whose file format cannot be handled directly by your app.

Use this class to present an appropriate user interface for previewing, opening, copying, or printing a specified file. For example, an email program might use this class to allow the user to preview attachments and open them in other apps.

After presenting its user interface, a document interaction controller handles all interactions needed to support file preview and menu display.

You can also use the delegate to participate in interactions occurring within the presented interface. For example, the delegate is notified when a file is about to be handed off to another application for opening. For a complete description of the methods you can implement in your delegate, see `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`.

Also check with [`QLPreviewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller) while handling Document related  tasks.